# I am trying to use an user HTML input to change a javascript object value

Tags: javascript, html, object

I am trying to use HTML 'input' to change apiData.id value. I'm new to javascript and not sure if this is correct. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const apiData = {
    url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/',
    type: 'pokemon',
    id: '76',
}

const input = document.getElementById('container');
const newId = apiData.id;

function eventController(event) {
    newId = event.target.value;
}
input.addEventListener('change', eventController, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pokemon</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <input id="input">
        <input type="submit" value="Catch">
    </div>




    <div class="pokemon"></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`newId` is const, so you cannot assign it with a new value after it has been declared.

But even if you could (and you can, by making it a variable), that would not affect `apiData.id`, as `newId` is assigned with the *value* of `apiData.id`, but they are not bound together.

You should just assign `apiData.id` directly with a new value:

```js
const apiData = {
    url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/',
    type: 'pokemon',
    id: '76',
}

const input = document.getElementById('container');
// const newId = apiData.id;

function eventController(event) {
    apiData.id = event.target.value;
}
input.addEventListener('change', eventController, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pokemon</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <input id="input">
        <input type="submit" value="Catch">
    </div>




    <div class="pokemon"></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply, I've made your suggested changes and it is still not using the input to change Pokemon ID. I have added a variable to display the input in an h1 tag which works but when I add the apiData.id it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Then there's another problem somewhere else in the code. In the portion of the code you've shared here there are no further problems. If you run it with my fix, enter some new id in the input field and press the button, `apiData` gets updated with the new id. You can easily verify that by adding `console.log(apiData);` right after `apiData.id = event.target.value;`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct! it does console.log the input but now I'm not sure why it isn't updating the details. Thank You Orius